# Angular2 basic Hello angular Program

Tags: angular

I am beginner to angular2, I am creating my first program of 'Hello angular' using it, when I run project from cmd then it runs fine but when I run it from Visual studio(Ctrl + F5) it shows console errors.(attached screenshot below), also I have attached screenshot of my solution explorer below. Any help please?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use angular with Visual Studio, you have to implement the Webpack configuration.

Here's a simple tutorial :
https://medium.com/@jonjam/combining-webpack-with-asp-net-mvc-5-a5bd07c49d0b

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Angular with Visual Studio Code rather than VS Community. Follow the steps listed in the Quick start https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng serve --open
```